# Issue importing/requiring pondjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, time-series

i would highly appreciate some help with the following issue. building a React app and trying to use Pondjs module for creating time series (main goal is to use React Timeseries Charts). I installed the version 0.8.9 of pond with npm because it is my understanding that newer versions have issues with React Timeseries Charts. I made a component to test the modules, the code is as follows:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    Charts,
    ChartContainer,
    ChartRow,
    YAxis,
    LineChart
} from "react-timeseries-charts";
import { TimeSeries, Index } from "pondjs";


class Chart extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const data1 = {
      name: 'Demanda (Wh) Galpon 1',
      columns: ["Hora", "Valor"],
      points: [
        [1400425947000, 2000],
        [1400425948000, 2100],
        [1400425949000, 2200],
        [1400425950000, 2300],
        [1400425951000, 2100],
      ]
    };
    const data2 = {
      name: 'Demanda (Wh) Galpon 2',
      columns: ["Hora", "Valor"],
      points: [
        [1400425947000, 1000],
        [1400425948000, 2000],
        [1400425949000, 3000],
        [1400425950000, 1500],
        [1400425951000, 2000],
      ]
    };
    const series1 = new TimeSeries(data1);
    const series2 = new TimeSeries(data2);
    return(
        <ChartContainer timeRange={series1.timerange()} width={800}>
          <ChartRow height="200">
            <YAxis id="axis1" label="AUD" min={0.5} max={1.5} width="60" type="linear" format="$,.2f"/>
            <Charts>
              <LineChart axis="axis1" series={series1} column={["aud"]}/>
              <LineChart axis="axis2" series={series2} column={["euro"]}/>
            </Charts>
            <YAxis id="axis2" label="Euro" min={0.5} max={1.5} width="80" type="linear" format="$,.2f"/>
          </ChartRow>
        </ChartContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

When running the app i get the following error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ0AW.png)

It seems there is an issue requiring so i also tried to require but i get the same error. I checked the node-modules installed and pondjs is there.

Answer (score 1):

In your columns, "Hora" should be "time" / "index" by default, you cannot name the first column by default since its your date. Then the rest of the columns should be fine.

This is what it should look like:

```
const data1 = {
      name: 'Demanda (Wh) Galpon 1',
      columns: ["time", "Valor"],
      points: [
        [1400425947000, 2000],
        [1400425948000, 2100],
        [1400425949000, 2200],
        [1400425950000, 2300],
        [1400425951000, 2100],
      ]
    };
    const data2 = {
      name: 'Demanda (Wh) Galpon 2',
      columns: ["time", "Valor"],
      points: [
        [1400425947000, 1000],
        [1400425948000, 2000],
        [1400425949000, 3000],
        [1400425950000, 1500],
        [1400425951000, 2000],
      ]
    };
```

I hope this helped!